# Next.js: getStaticProps not updating fetch values in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm basically developing a blog on Next.js. Because it is another team which is in charge of the back-end, I'm currently making fetch API calls from getStaticProps to get my articles even though it's better practice to make database queries directly:

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params, res }) {
    try {
        const result = await fetch(`${API.baseURL}/get_article/${params.id}`);
        const article = await result.json();

        return {
            props: { article },
        };
    } catch (error) {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        return { props: {} };
    }
}
```

While this works perfectly in development mode, getting the article, editing it, and then accessing it again does not work in production (even locally, with the built version).

I guess it has something to do with Next.js handling cache somehow... What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all the argument of function `getStaticProps` i.e the `context` object doesn't have any property named `res`. So `res.statusCode = 404;` doesn't do anything here.

And `getStaticProps` is meant be used for **static site generation**, additionally for dynamic routes, you can export another function `getStaticPaths` which should generate and return an array of paths with the dynamic route params for which `getStaticProps` will be called at **build time** for **pre-rendering** the pages.

In development mode, data-fetching methods will be called per-request basis so your code works. But in production mode, it will show the **pre-rendered static** pages which means the page will show the content as it was rendered and if you edit and update the content it will not reflect on the pages.

If you decide to go with static-site-generation either you have to rebuild the entire site after an update to a blog or you have to have some kind of **client-side** `data-fetching` logic that will update the blog when you update its content.

For client-side data-fetching you can use something like [swr](https://github.com/vercel/swr) or [react-query](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query)

Here is some psuedo-code which might help with pre-rendering the pages,

for route `/article/[articleId]`

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const articles = await /* db query to get the list of articles or fetch from remote API*/

  // generate a list of paths with route params
  const paths = articles.map(article => ({ params: { articleId: article.id }}))

  return {
     paths,
     fallback: false 
     // fallback can be  true if you want to show a fallback version of page 
     // and serve JSON for unknown articles
  }

}


export async function getStaticProps(ctx) {
    try {
        const result = await fetch(`${API.baseURL}/get_article/${params.id}`);
        const article = await result.json();

        return {
            props: { article },
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
          props: null
        }
    }
}
```

Learn more about how `fallback` works in returned value of function `getStaticPaths` [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required).

Another alternative is to use [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) as the data-fetching method which will be called on each request for the page, but TTFB(time to first byte) will be higher. So for a blog-post site, I will not suggest using `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer!
The purpose of using `getStaticProps` was to get the blog posts SEO friendly... Isn't a client-side data-fetching going to remove that?

Comment: The pages will be statically rendered with the data-populated, so you are never sending empty `HTML` which will be hydrated client-side. The role of `react-query` or `swr` in this case  will be to revalidate the data upon mount so the public blogs will always show the latest content. Also when somebody updates their posts they can see the updated content. BTW How often a blog will be updated?

Comment: If the update can happen too often, you can choose to use `getServerSideProps` but with a custom server that will have to implement some-sort of caching strategy.

Comment: What happens when there's a new post? That's an issue I had along with the post edition: the content of the article was empty to start with. Does this mean that if I don't rebuild the website, the new blog posts will not be SEO-friendly?

Comment: In case of new post additions you can use set `fallback: true` in the returned value of `getStaticPaths` this will serve a fallback version of the page (like a loading indicator) while nextjs serves the props for the new post as JSON. With google crawlers generally using fallback is not a problem for SEO. Read more about it [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12482)

Comment: Hi again, I've just finished trying using fallback: true + SWR. The data gets updated correctly thanks to SWR, but while testing using `curl`, I still don't get any update unless I build again...
Do you know if this is because of curl instead of Google? Or is it something I did wrong?

Comment: Yes, this happens because `curl` neither waits for nor tries to interpret client-side javascript. Also, this will be a similar behavior for other tools like `wget`, `nc` etc.

Comment: @Thanh-QuyNguyen, could you please share your snippet code?

Comment: Sorry but I actually stopped working on that project...

Answer (score 7):

You have to add the `revalidate` parameter. Find out more [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration).

In your case

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params, res }) {
    try {
        const result = await fetch(`${API.baseURL}/get_article/${params.id}`);
        const article = await result.json();

        return {
            props: { article },
            revalidate: 10 // 10 seconds 
        };
    } catch (error) {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        return { props: {} };
    }
}
```

Please note that `revalidate` parameter.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad I helped 

Comment: @GabrielArghire you are THE man. thanks

Comment: You're welcome, my friend 

Comment: I added the revalidate parameter, but the content is not updated after the predefined revalidation time, when the app is in production.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to update the HTML that is generated using getStaticProps, this process is called incremental server regeneration. This will ensure that your page is updated whenever you push an update to your blog post.
NextJS has documented this
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching
You search for ISR on the above page to understand how it's done
Basically you'll have to specify a time after which NextJS will try to update the page and in case there is a new post altogether, it will be server rendered on first request and then cached, once cached it'll work almost like a static page, refer fallback: 'blocking'
Quoting from website :
Next.js allows you to create or update static pages after you’ve built your site. Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) enables you to use static-generation on a per-page basis, without needing to rebuild the entire site. With ISR, you can retain the benefits of static while scaling to millions of pages.

Consider our previous getStaticProps example, but now with Incremental Static Regeneration enabled through the revalidate property

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.